# is UCK deprecated ? an alternative ? is it compatible to linux 16?

Tags: iso, custom-distributions, uck

I used UCK to compile amazing custom linux 14.04 ISOs.
when browsing the most updated reference i found was
https://www.linux.com/learn/roll-your-own-customized-ubuntu-uck
it is from 2013 and says nothing about Ubuntu 16 and/or new core.

Is it compatible ?

in their https://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/ page they say it is discontinued... (i am wonder why)

could someone recommends an alternative ?

thank you so much

Comment: Here is an alternative http://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image IDK if UCK will work on 16.04 though.

Comment: Still available in the Xenial repositories: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/uck

Answer (score 2):

Best alternative as of now https://github.com/kamilion/customizer   this was around before UCK and is still being developed today!

Comment: Can only be used to create an ISO with Ubuntu version number and architecture matching the host system.