# Create a Ubuntu Live CD with custom folders

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-cd, customization

I am trying to create a custom Live CD with all my folders inside.
I have created my own kiosk mode system and I have to install it in several computers at the same time.
I have tried copying the complete HD with the dd option

```
dd input output
```

But it's not fast enough in the installation, I can't wait 10-12 hours for every device for copying-pasting the HD.

So, can I make a custom Ubuntu Live version with all my files and all my configuration in it, and when install Ubuntu sets all like the original version?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Take a look at Cubic http://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to create an image of your system and clone that to other computers take a look at http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: @Katu You should convert that comment to an answer and drop me a comment and I'll come back and upvote it (be sure to include CloneZilla Server in your answer)

Comment: @Fabby, I posted a comment because I wasn't answering the question exactly, but I've trusted your reputation and created an answer now ;)

Comment: Thanks to all the commentaries. I am already working on it! If works, i validate the answer in a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to clone your installation to other computers, you can use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org). It's normally easier than creating your own iso, especially if you want to keep your configuration.

If all your machines are in the same network, you can use [The Fog Project](https://fogproject.org/). It's a computer cloning and management solution.

If you still want to create your own distribution, this is the official documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization