# Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator: "Warning! You are not in the chroot environment. Exiting."

Tags: iso, chroot

I'm using [CUBIC](https://launchpad.net/cubic) to create a custom Ubuntu ISO. I have downloaded ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso as a base image, and specified ~/cubicworkspace as my working folder. But when I click "Next" and [it is supposed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image) to bring me into the chroot-ed environment, I get:

> WARNING! You are NOT in the chroot environment. Exiting.

The host system is a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I confirmed squashfs-tools are installed. I can't find useful/relevant docs anywhere. Help? :)

I tried [following some manual creation steps here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) to the point where I ran `unsquashfs` and mounted a few system directories in the chroot, and then when I moved the "unsquashed FS" into the folder in my CUBIC workspace, I run cubic again, I do get:

> You are in the chroot environment.

And I can do some customizations, but then when I click Next, CUBIC says "You have exited from the terminal. Click the Back button to re-enter the chroot terminal." and the Next button is grayed out. :(

How do I fix this so that CUBIC just works? Apparently my little hack doesn't work to the point where I can actually make the image. And the wiki I linked to seems really outdated...

Comment: Try to execute at terminal session: `sudo cubic`

Comment: @Redbob "Cubic may not be run as a privileged user."

Comment: Did you see that? https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image/741770

Comment: @Redbob Yes, I even linked to that page in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question trying to solve the same problem. Since I couldn't find an answer, here is how I eventually solved it:

Cubic logs to `stdout`, which in my case was `~/.cache/lxsession/Lubuntu/run.log`.

Cubic expands the iso, then unsquashes the filesystem in the `casper/` folder. I found that the Ubuntu Server 16.04 ISO did not have a `casper/` folder, but the squashed filesystem was in `install/`.

I fixed it by running `sudo sed -i 's/casper/install/g' /usr/share/cubic/utilities.py`. **NOTE:** This modifies the Cubic code and is NOT reversible in the same way -- it'd be easiest to uninstall then reinstall it.

Apparently there is also a bug report about Cubic not supporting Ubuntu Server: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cubic/+bug/1743177

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Found this because I had the same issue, on my side I just deleted the project and restarted without changing the suggested iso name and it worked.

using 18.04
recent release of Cubic on clean minimal install

Comment: Most likely, the squash file system was not extracted fully (i.e. all the files under the root "/" directory could not be extracted from the original iso). When you deleted the project, the squash files system was extracted again, successfully.