# Is there a website or software for Windows (like Cubic in Ubuntu) in order to create a custom Ubuntu ISO?

Tags: windows, lubuntu, iso, customizer

I installed Cubic today on my Lubuntu 16.04 machine (on a partition, 3,5 GB free by the time of writing, on Cubic installation time the free space was about 4,2 GB) and when I selected the ISO (downloaded from official Lubuntu website, if you wonder) on Cubic in order to customize it, it just loaded the directory and the file name (lubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso).

[image: Cubic only loads minimal info]

*(Notice that there is no other information, neither Cubic lets me edit info in the "Custom ISO" area, nor lets me click on "Next".)*

I think that I have to extend the partition because on the guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image),
on one picture, the compressed Linux file system used 3,99 GB of space, and the final ISO image used 1,21 GB (5,2 GB in total).

So, is there a website like SUSE Studio or a Windows app in order to create custom Ubuntu ISOs?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Bajiru

Comment: It sounds like you have lots of space on your windows partition...  Have you tried to install VirtualBox in windows?  Then create a Lubuntu virtual machine, install Cubic in the virtual machine, and customize.  You might need to move the new ISO out of your VM to crate a bootable iso, or you may be able to do it directly from the VM if you can access your USB in the VM. (Finally, is your available 3.5 GM enough free space to run Lubuntu?)

Comment: @PJSingh I tried to install and run Cubic in an Ubuntu 14.04 VM with lots of free space, but the shared folder was broken. :(  My Lubuntu installation runs fine with 3.5-3.1 free GiBs of space. I'll try do delete an old partition with Ubuntu 12.04 on it in order to extend the free space.