# How can I create my own distro with live USB?

Tags: system-installation, usb, custom-distributions

I had heard of the Chinese DE called Deepin and decided to try it out for myself. It ended up becoming my favorite DE! It runs well, looks great, and has good compatibility with my Ubuntu 17.10 install. I would like to make my own Ubuntu flavor with Deepin as the main desktop. I just don't know how to make the live installer and all that. Is there any way to make a live Deepin Ubuntu installer that can install it onto a computer just like any other version of Ubuntu would? Even if I can't make it official it would at least be nice to give to my friends and use on my own computers!

Edit:
I guess I should mention that I am using Cubic now with the default Ubuntu desktop 17.10. I am trying to uninstall the Ubuntu desktop and GDM and instead use Deepin Desktop environment with LightDM. I also want to remove Nautilus, Gnome Photos, Gnome Games, etc. to replace them with the Deepin versions.

I also would like to point out that I've heard several people on these kinds of forums saying how much they wished that there was an official Deepin Ubuntu version and that someone would make it. I just figured that I'd try to do that myself. It may help bring the Ubuntu community together more.

Comment: Have you looked at the answers on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image)?

Comment: @pomsky: Cubic sounds interesting but will it allow you to add the Deepin desktop environment like the OP asked? I could not find how to do this in the answers.

Comment: @karel:  Your "duplicated" question makes no mention of replacing the desktop environment. Please let us know which current ISO respinner  will do this. I think this is a valid new question and not a duplicate. I do spend quite a bit of time trying to update bootable USB questions.

Comment: I added the Deepin PPA but when I try to install DDE it says that I need dependencies. It won't install the dependencies that are required for DDE. I even did sudo apt-get install -f.

Comment: These are just some errors I get. There's more but AskUbuntu doesn't have space.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dde : Depends: dde-desktop but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-polkit-agent but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-dock but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-launcher but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-control-center (> 2.90.5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: dde-daemon but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: deepin-metacity but it is not going to be

Comment: @c.s. so not true. The concept is still the same. And with questions like this you must be flexible and willing to get your hands dirty.  To the ts pick the askubuntu topic regarding the server version. That one negates the need to remove the desktop. And you start out without Nautilus

Comment: @Rinzwind: My understanding is there is more than one concept, some remastering tools add or remove packages to the ISO's, others create a Live installer from an installed system. I think the OP might be looking for the later as he has already made a version he likes. I am testing "Linux Live Kit", https://www.linux-live.org/ , and it is looking like a possible solution and is currently maintained.

Comment: Naah only one works... Manual.make it actually your own. no 3rd party tools. Those all are limited.

Comment: This wouldn't answer the question in the title, but have you tried the Ubuntu Deepin ISO linked in the [Deepin DE PPA description](https://launchpad.net/~leaeasy/+archive/ubuntu/dde)? It's hosted on baidu, so you may want to download the ISO with [JDownloader 2](http://jdownloader.org/), but I have tested it in a VM and it appears to be as close to an official Deepin Ubuntu version as you might get right now.

Comment: @fakedad I have actually tried this PPA on cubic but for some reason, it just refuses to install. Something about holding broken packages. However, doing the exact same process on my current install worked out fine.

Comment: I was referring to the link in the description of the PPA: "There are two livecd with dde 15.5, download links blow: Ubuntu Artful:链接：[http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i5gnThN](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i5gnThN) 密码：n9oq". It appears the maintainer of the PPA (or possibly someone associated with Deepin's development) has already created a Live CD image of Ubuntu 17.10 with all of the Deepin packages (including DE) installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: @fakedad The pages are all Chinese. I could translate it in Chrome though. The link for the Artful release doesn't have the download. It says "This link to share content may be due to infringement, pornography, reactionary, vulgar and other information, can not be accessed!"

Comment: That's interesting. That page previously had a download for a file "ubuntu-deepin-amd64.hybrid.iso", but it appears that it was taken down sometime in the past eight days (since I last tried it). I would contact [leaeasy](https://launchpad.net/~leaeasy), the maintainer of the Deepin DE PPA, and ask about it.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried the Ubuntu Deepin ISO out on a VM. I still have that ISO file that was originally on the website if you would like me to share it somewhere. However, I do not know why the file was taken down, so it may be better to investigate in case there was a problem with the file that I am unaware of.