# Ubuntu 16.04 and Cubic for customised Kernel

Tags: 16.04, kernel, dell, raid

There is a similar question asked previously but it did not contain a working solution.

Background - I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 server on a Dell server with H740p PERC or RAID card.

Problem - setup is not able to detect the HDD during installation.

According to [this post](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201706-25552/), 16.04 does not recognize this RAID card and it recommends using 16.4.4 HWE Kernel and from another post, someone got it to detect the disks using kernel v4.11.12 and this is what I am attempting to do.

What I attempted next is to use Cubic (referring to [this](https://www.ostechnix.com/create-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image/)) and to try to add the v4.11.12 Kernel but it is failing during the chroot step.

The Error message is:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/share/cubic# if [ "$(id -u)" == 0 ] && [ "$(stat -c %d:%i /)" != "$(stat -c %d:%i /proc/1/root/.)" ]; then clear; echo "
> $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 2)You are in the chroot environment.$(tput sgr0)
> "; else clear; echo "
> $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)WARNING! You are in NOT the chroot environment. 
Exiting.$(tput sgr0)
> "; exit; fi

WARNING! You are in NOT the chroot environment. Exiting.
```

I am running cubic using `userA` account that has `sudo` privileges and not `root`.
Can anyone please provide some pointers as to how I can get past this?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: the text in the link you referenced above was plagiarized from https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image/741770#741770

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by downloading the recently released Ubuntu 16.04.4 and installing the HWE Kernel option when you are booting via ISO.

Thanks!