# Can't connect to internet in chroot using Cubic

Tags: 18.04, chroot, custom-distributions

Currently trying to modify a custom ISO image using Cubic.

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), I am supposed to enter

```
ln -sr /run/systemd/resolve/resolve.conf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolve.conf
```

But what is returned is

```
ln:failed to create symbolic link '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolve.conf': no such file or directory
```

Even `hostname -i` doesn't resolve.

How can I get internet access on it since I need to use apt.

Comment: There's an extra `e` in `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolve.conf` compared to the command you have shown above. I'd suggest checking for typos.

Comment: @muru, just checked, used the correct command with ` e `, same error, will fix the typo.

Comment: The post you linked to says `resolv.conf` without an `e`

Comment: @muru, I made the edit, is that the correct command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create the folder /run/systemd/resolve with mkdir :

```
mkdir /run/systemd/resolve
```

then you can create the link with:

```
ln -sr /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```