# Configuring services in Cubic chroot

Tags: server, chroot, configure

There's an excellent "using Cubic" [guide already posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image#), but it didn't get into how to configure services in the Cubic chroot.  For instance, I would like to pre-configure a RabbitMQ server so that it's ready-to-use after the .iso has been installed, but commands like:

```
service rabbitmq-server start
```

are met with responses like:

```
Running in chroot, ignoring request: is-active
Running in chroot, ignoring request: show ...
Running in chroot, ignoring request: show
Running in chroot, ignoring request: start
```

Is it feasible to pre-configure a custom service to be running on first boot (or first login) after installing an .iso made with Cubic?

If so, what's an efficient approach?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you found any workaround on this?

Comment: Basically, ignore the messages, it _seems_ o.k., works fine while running, though I am having issues with rabbitmq-server blocking the shutdown operation (waits 90 seconds, then dies)... Other services like openssh-server, samba and virtualbox seem to be fine even with these ignoring messages.  Then, there's the ultimate workaround which is to just do the installation after the .iso installs with a script that you run on first boot (either manually, or even automatically one time.)