# define partition in custom iso file

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, partitioning

I am building custom iso for Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04. Is there anyway I can define partition in the iso? I am using cubic to build the iso.

Thanks,
Zain

Comment: [Cubic makes it easy for you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image) to make a custom ISO.  *If you want all the whistles and bells of a custom ISO, **you need to do it [the hard way](https://askubuntu.com/a/49679/344926)***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)