# How to inject network drivers into Ubuntu Iso?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, ubuntu-drivers, custom-distributions, additional-drivers

how to inject network drivers into the ubuntu OS iso? I went through the [Cubic to create a custom Ubuntu live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741753/how-to-use-cubic-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-live-cd-image).

But it doesn't say anything about injecting the drivers, only to install packages. What if I get kernel modules to put into the iso image?
Here, suppose I need to inject intel driver into the iso, then I can make a directory inside the kernel tree directory:
`/lib/modules/$Kernel_version/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/`

What if I have a custom driver, what needs to be done for it?

Comment: Intel drivers for network devices or graphics are already included.

Comment: I just took an example. If I have a custom driver then? I modified the question for clearance.

Comment: Package it as deb then add it like any other package?