# Modifying installer program for custom-built version of Ubuntu on Live CD

Tags: system-installation, custom-distributions

I'm making my own Ubuntu based distribution called Focus OS but I'm confused as to how I am meant to put the "Install Focus OS" program on the Live CD, can someone help me with this please?

Like this but with Install Focus OS on it instead:
[image: Like this but with Install Focus OS on it instead]

Comment: do you mean you have all customization's done and you are looking for the name change only?

Comment: yeah, im just wanting the program on the desktop that'll say Install FocusOS

Comment: I used Linux Live Kit to create the Bootable ISO but i think that is slax based so im not sure wat to do, should I use something else and if yes, what would you reccommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the name is coming from the file

```
/usr/share/applications/ubiquity.desktop
```

So edit that file while you are customizing the ISO.

[image]

In the image you can notice that, I used  [CUBIC](https://launchpad.net/cubic)  application to customize the ISO.

[image]

Comment: So how would I go about doing this on LXDE instead?

Comment: Make sure you use the Lubuntu ISO (https://lubuntu.net/downloads/) for an Ubuntu based LXDE, and follow the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/100356. Then make the change as Pratap pointed out.