# Added packages missing in the modified Ubuntu with Cubic

Tags: custom-distributions

I install Ubuntu frequently on new systems and always I have to install certain but the same packages, so I've searched this and seems like I can use Cubic for this exact problem.

So I followed the instructions [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic/) and in the chroot I installed apache2 (and also made sure it was installed correctly), then I proceed to create the modified ISO. Also in the part which suggests "removing" packages for either typical or minimal mode, I **didn't** check the apache2 package, so it was there unchecked and my expectation was that it should be pre-installed in my new Ubuntu ISO image, but after installing the new ISO, the apache2 isn't there. Any ideas which step I may be taking wrong? or even maybe I have a misunderstanding of the purpose of the Cubic?

Almost the same instructions are also in [this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/883154) and nothing in it seems different to me compared to what I've done.

Comment: You were correct in *not* check-marking the apache2 package on the Packages page. How did you install apache (`sudo apt install apache2`) ? How did you verify that it was installed in Cubic? How did you identify that apache was not installed on your customized ISO?

Comment: @PJSingh Thank you for the comment. My issue is solved now(Should I delete the question now or leave it here?). I verified it was installed in Cubic by `service --status-all`, and verified it was not installed in the customized ISO by installing it and running the same command, and also the command `pip list | grep apache`. For some reason, the next time I tried it it worked, I should have made a mistake the first time.

Comment: Instead of deleting your question, you can help others in the community by posting your answer to your own question. Use the "Your Answer" box below. (You'll get some reputation points for doing this). Then click the check-mark next to your answer to accept it, so people know that it solves the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was fixed the second time I tried. Dumb mistake I possibly made:

- Not installing the packages correctly in the chroot step. E.g.: if you use APT, you can confirm that the package you installed is actually in the list of installed packages using `apt list | grep <package-name>`.
- One other really silly mistake is using the main ISO instead of the customized one! So make sure you're using the generated ISO by the Cubic and not the main one.