# Editing Ubuntu ISO with Cubic to skip the disk check?

Tags: live-usb, custom-installer

Is there any way to skip the disk check in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS by editing the ISO with Cubic? If possible, can we edit it in such a way that I get a new menu-entry on the try/install page. So, right above the "Try Ubuntu without installing", I'll have something like "Try Ubuntu (Custom)" which skips the disk check?

Edit: Please excuse my bad habit of referring to 20.04 LTS as 20 LTS

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 LTS.

Comment: Are you talking about Ubuntu Core 20?  (the *year* format is reserved for *snap* only products such as Ubuntu Core 20, they all come with 10 years of supported life so the LTS isn't usually mentioned for *year* format releases)

Comment: **Please tell us the *name of the iso file*, that you want to modify**. I think you will get what you want, if you use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a persistent live drive. In such a drive you can select different options to boot at the grub menu also live-only boot options, and if still necessary you can easily edit the `grub.cfg` file in partition #3 of the pendrive to skip the disk check in every option. (This is easier than to make a new iso file.)

Comment: Hey all, I meant to say 20.04 LTS. I keep saying 20 though. Bit of a bad habit

Comment: Hey @sudodus, I did consider going the mkusb route, but I really like the idea of modifying the ISO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll assume you mean Ubuntu 20.04 or Ubuntu 20.10. The process is the same for Ubuntu desktop releases.

In [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic), when you get to the [Options page](https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/100356), click on the Boot tab and edit the files shown.

For the `boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `boot/grub/loopback.cfg` files, create a new `menuentry` item, such as "Try Ubuntu (Custom)" with the parameter `fsck.mode=skip` added to the `linux` line.

For the `isolinux/txt.cfg` file, create a new `label` item, such as "live-no-fsck" with the parameter `fsck.mode=skip` added `append` line.

For example, in the file `boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu (Custom)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper fsck.mode=skip file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

For example, in the file `boot/grub/loopback.cfg`:

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu (Custom)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper fsck.mode=skip file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

For example, in the file `isolinux/txt.cfg`:

```
default live-no-fsck
label live-no-fsck
  menu label ^Try Ubuntu (Custom)
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  boot=casper fsck.mode=skip file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
```

Note that in the `boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `boot/grub/loopback.cfg` files, the first entry is default. In `isolinux/txt.cfg`, you specify the default entry using the directive `default <your default entry>`.

(Also, be aware that this only affects the ISO boot. If you want the same behavior for an installed system, you will need to modify grub in Cubic's Terminal page, and you will need to take special steps in the preseed file to ensure your customized grub is not overwritten during installation.)

Here is a screenshot of Cubic's Options page, Boot tab, showing a new menu entry that skips the file system check.

[image: Screenshot of Cubic's Options page, Boot tab]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for