# Editing the Ubuntu ISO to skip try/install page with Cubic?

Tags: live-usb, custom-installer

Edit: Many people have been linking [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361056/editing-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic-to-skip-the-disk-check) as a duplicate of the current question. While the process would probably be similar, I do not believe the steps would be exactly the same. The linked post shows how to skip this:

[image]

As can be seen from the 2 different screenshots, this is not what I'm trying to achieve here. If I am mistaken, please comment below.

I was wondering if anyone could take me through the process of editing the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO with Cubic to skip this page:

[image]

and go right into the live session?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing Ubuntu ISO with Cubic to skip the disk check?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361056/editing-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic-to-skip-the-disk-check)

Comment: @leoperbo not quite? I mean the linked post goes into skipping the disk check process right? That's the black screen with "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress"? But that's not what I'm looking to bypass here.

Comment: @user68186 wait, is that what the confusion is about? Thing is, this is one of the few clear images of the try/install page I could find online. The arrow was there to begin with. I definitely want to skip to the live session. I'll try to edit that arrow out, if that helps but I still don't understand why everyone is linking this post --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361056/editing-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic-to-skip-the-disk-check

Comment: After you disable the "Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu" pop-up dialog, do you *still* want the ability to install Ubuntu from the Live environment by clicking on the Install desktop or dock icon?

Comment: @PJSingh I intend to use this as just a live USB so I don't require the ability to install from this ISO. But thanks for explaining both methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options to boot directly into the desktop environment, without displaying the "Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu" dialog:

1. Lose the ability to install Ubuntu from the Live environment
2. Retain the ability to install Ubuntu from the Live environment

**Option 1: Lose the ability to install Ubuntu from the Live environment**

Remove the Ubiquity installer. On [Cubic's Terminal page](https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/100356), execute the following:

```
apt autoremove --purge ubiquity ubiquity-casper ubiquity-frontend-gtk ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork
```

(Note: The package `ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu` may be different for your flavor of Ubuntu. For example, it could be `ubiquity-slideshow-kubuntu`, or `ubiquity-slideshow-xubuntu`, etc.)

This will log you directly into the Live environment. However, there will be no *Install Ubuntu* icon on the desktop or in the dock. You will not be able to install Ubuntu from this Live environment.

**Option 2: Retain the ability to install Ubuntu from the Live environment**

Disable the Ubiquity service. On [Cubic's Terminal page](https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/100356), execute the following:

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/ubiquity.service
```

This will log you directly into the Live environment. The *Install Ubuntu* icon will remain on the desktop and the dock. You will still be able to install Ubuntu from this Live environment by clicking on one of these icons.

Comment: Testing in Ubuntu 22.04, it appears `rm /etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants/ubiquity.service` results in the install option being removed from the desktop as well