# Ubuntu distro custom and add-apt-repository

Tags: 20.04, bash, package-management, custom-distributions, add-apt-repository

I edited the `/etc/lsb-release` and `/usr/lib/os-release` files, then created the `/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release` path with the original `lsb-release` file.
the `add-apt-repository` command no longer works `NoDistroTemplateException` after this change but the change IS REQUIRED because I want to release my distro.
How do I make it work the same?

/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
```

/etc/lsb-release:

```
DISTRIB_ID=MYDISTRO
DISTRIB_RELEASE=1.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME=mycodename
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="MYDISTRO 1.0.0"
```

/usr/lib/os-release:

```
NAME="MYDISTRO"
VERSION="1.0.0 (MyCodeName)"
ID=mydistro
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="MYDISTRO 1.0.0"
VERSION_ID="1.0"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=mycodename
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

For privacy reasons I cannot write the real name of the distro and I changed it with `MYDISTRO` and with `MyCodeName`

Comment: seems like your base_files cannot read your distro. try to create new file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/base-files` add the contents `Package: base-files
Pin: release o=MYDISTRO
Pin-Priority: 1001`. That will force your default version, be carefull about typographical errors.

Comment: That file does not work

Comment: what the error output of `add-apt-repository` command on your distro ?

Comment: `aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Mydistro/mycodename`

The problem is caused from line 3 and line 11 of `os-release` file.

Comment: you cannot customizing the template manualy, many Custumization tools to do that. the tools that i tried are [Ubuntu Builder](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder), OS Builder, UCK, Cubic, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: How can I customize it with Cubic? I use Cubic in fact.

Comment: try this [Tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/856659)

Comment: These 2 links didn't help me.