Custom /casper/vmlinuz /casper/initrd for ARM64 Ubuntu Server install ISO image
I have a set of systems that needs a custom Linux kernel image to support the hardware. With previous releases I was able to copy the working vmlinuz and update the initrd files for that kernel in the casper directory on the install ISO and recreate the ISO image and it would boot and work fine.
The 24.04 release has changed to use compressed modules instead of a compressed initrd. I am building kernel debian packages using the Canonical process (fakeroot debian/rules binary) and they all seem to work fine on a running system.
I have analysed the contents of the initrd file (see below) and the one created while installing my built kernel packages seems to match. However when I use the vmlinuz and initrd images produced for ISO image when I try to boot I get:
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... [    1.781241] Btrfs loaded, zoned=yes, fsverity=yes
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
done.
No root device specified. Boot arguments must include a root= parameter.

I have compared the contents of the original initrd and my initrd images. My initrd has the same file list execpt the particular directory name in /usr/lib/modules matches the version of my kernel.  The directory structure and the particular *.ko.zst files all the have the same names and the "file" command shows then are the same type (.kernel/fs/nls/nls_ucs2_utils.ko.zst: Zstandard compressed data (v0.8+), Dictionary ID: None).
In the 22.04 ISO I had to recreate the initrd image because it included a number of other directories besides /usr/lib/{modules, firmware}.  It was more than just the modules and included the bin, etc, lib, sbin, etc. directories to make it a boot to ramdisk type image I expected was needed for a live image system.
Something basic has changed between 22.04 and 24.04. Please let me know the process needed to update the /casper/vmlinuz and /casper/initrd files for the 24.04 ISO.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Johnnie

Install casper in the current Ubuntu by sudo apt install casper. this will generate new vmlinuz-* and intird-img-* files (in  the /boot directory) used to boot with the live session. copy these files to the /casper directory and rename them to vmlinuz and initrd. after that you can remove casper from the current Ubuntu.

try like this Linux line in the menu entry linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/noble-desktop-amd64.iso --

Hi Talaat, thanks for responding.  I tried the "sudo apt install casper". The vmlinuz image did not change but it did create an initrd image with a new time stamp. I compared the contents of the new initrd with the one generated by the install of the package for that kernel.  The contents are the same.
The result is I get the same error.
I do not understand you second suggestion. I am creating the ISO image, dd'ing it to a USB drive and using that to install a system I could very well be missing the point but how would this find a particular iso image name?

the second suggestion is related to booting directly from an ISO file. you can change the Iso name to match your iso name.

if you will use dd method, edit grub.cfg and specify the *.squashfs name in the Linux line like this example linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper layerfs-path=filesystem.squashfs --

you can use cubic to customize the ISO file, update the packages and update the initrd file. see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/741770/1698042

Making progress. I now have the grub.cfg with "linux /casper/vmlinuz boot=casper layerfs-path=ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.generic.squashfs autoinstall ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/server/ ---". This starts the install fine but it fails due to missing the dm-multipath.ko module.  It is missing in my ramdisk but it was also missing in the 22.04 ramdisk and I had to add it.

I tried to rebuild the ramdisk and add it equivelent to the way I did with 22.04.  I no longe need to compress the new ramdisk so I uncpioed it. add the miissing module to the file list and then use "find . -print | cpio -o -H newc  > ../iso-dir/casper/initrd" to rebuild the ram disk image.  The booting kernel did not fined the initrd imaga correct.  So I also added a depmod call in the process like I needed on 22.04 but that still does not work.

On 22.04 I also had to add dm-multiplath to the list of modules in the ramdisk in the conf/modules file but that does not now exist.  I tried a kernel with this driver builtin but the 22.04 still failed because the install wanted to load it as a module.
